# Replicating Correlation ID like functionality in apache kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

We are implementing apache kafka as a distributed messaging middleware that would be exhaustively used for asynchronous communications.

I have a few use cases where i want to be able to publish a message to the kafka broker and listen for a reply to that particular message (like we would using correlation id in rabbit mq).

I read about the apache kafka protocol and seems like they do use the correlation id internally. But i couldn't find any examples that are using that correlation id anywhere.

Can you please suggest if there is way to do that with apache kafka?

Answer (score 1):

That is a part of their network communication protocol.

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/A+Guide+To+The+Kafka+Protocol#AGuideToTheKafkaProtocol-Requests

[Correlation Id in Apache kafka](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23760587/correlation-id-in-apache-kafka)

That is not about user's request-reply scenarios.

You should consider to use some part of `payload` as a `correlationKey` to track *business* replies for *business* requests.

Since version 2.0 (under development) Spring Kafka supports Apache Kafka 0.11 with its Headers support. So, instead of `payload` hacking you can use some header on the matter for correlation.

You also can follow with the progress in the Spring Integration Kafka for gateways support where request-reply is the central functionality. Therefore correlation is very important there: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-kafka/pull/162